# How the amount that is wagered influences the way bankroll goes?

Tags: probability

I found the following question on the internet:

> A player sits down at a gambling table to play a game with 1000 dollars. He bets 1 dollar at a time with probability of winning being equal to 49.3212% with a 1:1 payout. What is the probability that the player's bankroll reaches 1200 before he goes bust?

I think the question is pretty interesting. Here's the answer:

$$\frac{\left (\frac{1-p}{p}  \right ) ^{1000} - 1}{\left (\frac{1-p}{p}  \right ) ^{1200} - 1}= \frac{\left (\frac{0.506788}{0.493212}  \right ) ^{1000} - 1}{\left (\frac{0.506788}{0.493212}  \right ) ^{1200} - 1} \approx .004378132$$

Now the answer also states that if instead of betting 1 dollar each time the player decides to bet the following amounts, the probability of reaching 1200 before losing the initial 1000 dollars also changes as follows:

> 5: 0.336507
>
> 10: 0.564184
>
> 25: 0.731927
>
> 50: 0.785049
>
> 100: 0.809914

How are those numbers found? The initial formula doesn't include the **amount wagered** as a variable. So how are those different probabilities are found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value 1000 in the formulas is \$1000 (the original amount) divided by \$1 (the wager). If you increase the bets to \$25, you have \$1000/\$25 = 40 bets' worth of money. I trust you can take it from here?

Comment: I got that part. I mean like, if instead of paying 1:1 it paid 2:1 when won. (Like betting on the first 12 numbers)

Comment: @SarpSTA: I see. I think that's different enough to be a new question -- I'm not sure you can use the same setup when you want a different number of rounds depending on the outcome. I can't immediately see the answer although I'm sure someone can help you.

Comment: I'll be posting a new one then. Thank you!

Comment: @SarpSTA: Good luck with your new question.

Comment: Can I ask one final question? When there is no house edge, the formula ends up being $$\frac{0}{0}$$ How to approach in this case?

Comment: @SarpSTA: with no house edge and probability $1$ of ending at $0$ or $1200$, expectations can be used to show the probability of ending at $1200$ must be $\frac{1000}{1200}$ no matter what size bets you make (you can even mix bet sizes)

Comment: @Henry But, for example if we bet the 1000 at once, then shouldn't it be %50? Edit: Stupid question, since the target is 1200.